How to find the value of $\lambda$ such that the new orbit of a satellite just touches the moon's surface
A satellite with speed $V$ moves in a circular orbit around the moon. The radius of the orbit is twice the radius of the moon and the orbit's centre coincides with the moon's centre. Its speed is suddenly reduced to $\lambda V$ where $0<\lambda<1$; find the value of $\lambda$ such that the new orbit just touches the surface of the moon.
I have that initially, the velocity of the satellite in the circular orbit is given by $V=\sqrt{\frac{GM}{2l}}$, where $G$ is Newton's Gravitational constant, $M$ is the mass of the moon and $l$ is the radius of the moon. Also, the total energy is given by $E=\frac{1}{2}mV^2-\frac{GMm}{2l}$, where $m$ is the mass of the satellite. Substituting the previous expression for $V$ into this equation gives;
$$
\begin{align}
E&=\frac{1}{2}m\frac{GM}{2l}-\frac{GMm}{2l}\\
&= -\frac{GMm}{4l}
\end{align}
$$
Now, the speed is reduced to $\lambda V$. We want the value of $\lambda$ such that the new (elliptical) orbit just touches the moon's surface (ie the perihelion occurs at $r=l$). Thus, the potential at this point is given by $-\frac{GMm}{l}$ and the speed is of course $\lambda V$. Then, since energy is conserved, we have
$$
\begin{align}
E=-\frac{GMm}{4l}&=\frac{1}{2}m\lambda^2V^2-\frac{GMm}{l} \\
&=\frac{1}{2}m\lambda^2\frac{GM}{2l}-\frac{GMm}{l} \\
&=\lambda^2\frac{GMm}{4l}-\frac{GMm}{l} \\
\implies -1&=\lambda^2-4 \\
\implies 0 &= \lambda^2-3 \\
\implies \lambda&=\sqrt{3}
\end{align}
$$
This obviously is wrong as it implies the satellite speeds up to touch the moon's surface. What is the problem? Have I made a logical error?

Is $l$ the radius of the moon, or the radius of the orbit? I assume $r$ is the other, but you don't define it. I ask the question because if $l$ is the radius of the moon, not the orbit, then your first equation should have $r$, not $l$. The orbital velocity is a function of the orbit height, not the radius of the object being orbited (which is generally only of interest in orbital calculations to avoid unintentional "landings").

But your real mistake is "since energy is conserved". The velocity just suddenly changed. How would energy be conserved? The only way that could happen is if the lost kinetic energy was converted into potential energy. I.e., the satellite also suddenly jumped into a higher orbit. But nothing like that is mentioned, so presumably the satellite is still at the same height, meaning the potential energy is unchanged, while the kinetic energy dropped by $\lambda^2$.

Also, just FYI - the correct term for an orbit about any body is "periapsis". Those not in astronomy or space flight will often use "perigee", but technically that refers to orbits about the Earth, while "perihelion" refers strictly to orbits about the sun (= "helios" in Greek).
